# handling actions from buttons inside TableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a table view with cells that contain a notification button, when pressed should schedule a location based notification with coordinate values from the respective cell.
How do i associate the button to the corresponding cell so that the correct latitude, longitude value is passed in the `CLCircularRegion` function.
i have read a few posts about using `indexPath.row`. But i cant really figure it out.
please provide me with a sample code in swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one section in your `tableView` and use custom `UITableViewCell` subclass, you can set cell's button's `tag` property to `indexPath.row` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and add action to it, for example:

```
cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
cell.button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("cellButtonPressed:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

After this implement action method:

```
func cellButtonPressed(button : UIButton){
  let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: button.tag, inSection:0)

  let longitude = cell.longitude // or whatever you store location
  let latitude = cell.latitude 

 // deal with received data

}
```

Comment: it's a mistake to build a table view cell in the action method.  building the index path is right, but then use that index path to access the model the same way `cellForRowAtIndexPath` must do.

Comment: I'm not building cell in the action method, the task was to get proper data from cell so I access it by using `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, where `row` is clicked button's tag. @sumesh didn't provide any `dataSource` code, so I can only assume how he builds cells.

Comment: @njuri thanx. I have one more question now. I want to change the image when the user clicks the button, lets say "B.png". but when he clicks again the image should change back to "A.png". how do i do it ? previously i was using tag to do this, but now that i am using tag to detect button press i cant use it to change button image. Is there any other way ?

Comment: You can add a boolean `selected` property to your cell, and set its value accordingly in `cellButtonPressed`. E.g ( `if cell.selected { cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named:"A.png")  cell.selected = false } else{//...}`

Comment: @njuri - `cellForRowAtIndexPath` dequeues (which may allocate) a *view*.  So what you're proposing to convey the model at an index path is to build a view, populate it with a (often impoverished) part of the model, return that view, then dig around in it for the model.  This is probably harmless, but a little absurd (and not always harmless).  From your comment, I think you understand this.  To operationalize your knowledge, instruct the OP to get the model at the index path and use that.

Comment: Also, tableView responds to `indexPathsOfSelectedRows`, so a selected boolean on a cell is superfluous.  (And also not harmless if you fail to keep the flag updated as the cell is reused.

Comment: As I said before I don't know how @sumesh builds his cells. If he has for example `locationsArray`, where are all locations stored and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` he calls e.g. `let currentLocation = locationsArray[indexPath.row]` and then sets the labels and stuff, then to get location data in `cellButtonPressed` there's no need to call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for getting location data, just use `let currentLocation = locationsArray[indexPath.row]` again to deal with clicked location.